# Does Alpacajs have a "button" type (how can I create a button anywhere)?

Tags: javascript, jsonschema, alpacajs

**Background:** I am working on creating an editor for an `Electron` desktop based project. The project uses JSON to store its data so a JSON schema-based editor would be a real boost. I have tried the [JSON Schema Based Editor](https://github.com/jdorn/json-editor) and while it is pretty good, it's development status is a bit sketchy at present. `Alpacajs` seems a much more active project but I am still trying to sort out if I can get it to do what I need.

**Question** How can I create in-line buttons with `Alpaca`? Although I have seen references to a `button` type, it throws an error when I specify that as the type. The [docs](http://www.alpacajs.org/documentation.html#fields) don't mentions a "button" type field among the built-in fields.

The image below shows what I am trying to do: have a button in-line with the "Project Path" field. I've tried a variety of things with no success (failed code below).

Can someone tell me what I am missing? Is it not possible to drop a button in anywhere? I need it for selecting assets, etc. This is a desktop app so the html5 file picker is not suitable.

---

[image]

---

I've tried using a template to specify a button (snippet):

```
 <div data-alpaca-layout-binding="projectName"></div>
    <div data-alpaca-layout-binding="projectVersion"></div>
    <div data-alpaca-layout-binding="path">
        <button onClick="getJSON()">Set Path</button>
        <div data-alpaca-layout-binding="projectPath"></div>
    </div>
```

---

My set up code is below. I've tried lots of variations – trying to reference the template, trying to just declare "button" as a type.

---

```
 var schema = {
    "title": "Project Info",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "projectName": {
        "title": "Project Name",
        "description": "Name of project",
        "type": "string",
        "required": false
      },
      "projectVersion": {
        "type": "string",
        "title": "Project Version",
        "description": "Project version number",
      },
      "path": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "projectPath": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Project Path"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  var options = {
    "fields": {
      "projectName": {
        "size": 5,
      }
    }
  }

  $("#form").alpaca({
    "schema": schema,
    "options": options,
    "view": {
      "parent": "bootstrap-edit-horizontal",
      "layout": {
        "template": './timeline-template1.html',
      },
      "wizard": {
        "renderWizard": true,
        "statusBar": true,
        "validation": false,
        "showSteps": true,
        "showProgressBar": false
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define buttons inside the form's ***options*** block. The button definitions must then be enclosed in a ***form*** block inside the *options* block.

Here is an example of a button I used to help me debug an Alpaca application. In addition to a button to submit the form ("Save Data"), this code displays a button with the label "Show JSON". When the button is clicked, the function displays a JavaScript alert popup containing the form's JSON data.

```
,"options": { 
    "form": {  
        "buttons": {
            "submit": {
                "label": "Save Data",
                "click": function(e) {
                    /* function does ajax submit to save my form data */
                }
            },
            "show": {
                "title": "Show JSON",
                "click": function() {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(this.getValue()));
                } // close 'click' block
            } // close 'show' block
        } // close 'buttons' block
    } // close 'form' block
} // end 'options' block
```

You can affect the button placement by changing the button container's style information. My user wanted the submit button (my "Save Data" button) at the top right corner of the screen, which I managed with the following style override:

```
/* Alpaca form button container has no space between it and right edge.
   Override it to add 10px of padding to right side. */
   Also move it to a fixed position at the top right corner of the screen */
.alpaca-form-buttons-container {
    padding-right: 10px !important;
    /* move button location to top right, no scroll */
    position: fixed;
    top: 88px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

You can also change button default properties, i.e. color, background, etc. using styles like:

```
.btn-default {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #eef6fd;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
.btn-default:hover {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #afdefa;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Alex

Comment: hi @Alex - thanks for answering this question. new to alpacajs  - where would these two overwrites live in the body? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I asked the question over on the [Alpaca github site](https://github.com/gitana/alpaca/issues/613) and received the answer below. It works.

> You can find the template for a form element here:
>   https://github.com/gitana/alpaca/blob/master/src/templates/web-edit/control.html
>   In your case, the property path is: /path/projectPath Copy the
>   template from above and paste it into your options as follows:

```
{
    ...
    "options": {
        "view": {
            "fields": {
                "/path/project/path": {
                    "templates": {
                        "control": `INSERT TEMPLATE HERE`
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

> Please note the quotation marks. Now you can insert the button into
>   the template, but you are on your own when it comes to event
>   handling...